# Manually login user from another application

Tags: meteor

I want to share user accounts in my new meteor application with an existing Ruby on Rails application. I've setup a rest endpoint using https://atmospherejs.com/package/http-methods that the rails app can call to create a user record using `Meteor.users.insert` (I'm not sure if this is the correct way to create users) . Now I want the users to be able to click a link in the existing rails app and be automatically logged into the meteor application.

Is there a way to manually log a user into a meteor application, possible by using some kind of unique token in a cookie or localstorage or just with a special url or something?

Answer (score 0):

If they've already created an account, which seems like they have. Then you can use the following method to log them in manually (this assumes you're use the `password` authentication).

Here is the method `Meteor.loginWithPassword(user, password, [callback])`

The callback is called with no arguments on success and with a single `error` argument on failure.

You can have them put their password/username on your other application and then just send that over through url parameters (there is probably a way more secure and better way of doing this though) using iron-router. Then you can run the function above in iron-router with the correct parameters.

This is just one way of doing it using the url-method. If you've got the user's meteor account data stored in the rails app then you don't need to go through the trouble of asking the user their `username` and `password` on your rails application.

I recommend looking into `iron-router` if you want to go through the url route.

Comment: He is not looking for the obvious way of logging a user in on the platform. He is trying to set up an Auth2.0 kind of atmosphere. He needs a solution to manually checking the users credentials and going from there.